# Drawing a path and then editing it for Android based devices

Tags: android, path, drawing, editing

I need a drawing application something like below -

User touches (ACTION_DOWN) the screen at Point A and then hovers (ACTION_MOVE) the finger on screen. Let's say current touch point is Point B. Application should always draw a straight line between A and B. That is, Point A of line will be static, while Point B of line will keep moving with the finger (touch-point). Once user lifts the finger, line becomes stable. User can draw multiple lines like this. Also, user can select (in selection mode) any line and change it's location.

Please suggest the way forward. What kind of drawing should I do, line/point/path/sprite/anything else? It would be really helpful, if you can provide any link. It should work on v3.2 and above.

Regards,
Prasoon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In above code, old line get disappears when you draw new line so use this to solve this problem..........

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Drawing drawing;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        LinearLayout linearLayout1= (LinearLayout) (findViewById(R.id.layout1));
        drawing=new Drawing(this);
        linearLayout1.addView(drawing);
        LinearLayout linearLayout2=(LinearLayout) (findViewById(R.id.layout2));
        linearLayout2.addView(new Drawing(this));
    }



class Drawing extends View{
    private Canvas mCanvas = null;
    private Path mPath = null;
    private Paint mBitmapPaint = null;
    private Bitmap mBitmap = null;
    private Bitmap bit=null;
    private Paint mPaint = null;
    private MainActivity baseMainActivity = null;

    public Drawing(Context c) {
        super(c);
        baseMainActivity=(MainActivity) c;
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(6);//This sets the width of signature

        Display display =baseMainActivity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();

        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(display.getWidth(), display.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);// 320*480  // For setting size of screen to draw Bitmap

        mPath = new Path();
        mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
        mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
        onDraw(mCanvas);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        try{
            canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);//Color.WHITE //To change background color of Application
            if(bit!=null)
                canvas.drawBitmap(bit, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
            else
                canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);

        }catch(Exception e){}
        if(bit==null)
            canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);

        bit=null;

    }
    private float mX, mY;
    private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
        mPath.reset();
        mPath.moveTo(x, y);
        mX = x+1;
        mY = y+1;

    }

    private void touch_upline(float x,float y) {
        mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
        mCanvas.drawLine(mX, mY, x, y, mPaint);
        mPath.reset();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            touch_start(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            eraseAll();
            touch_upline(x, y);
            invalidate();


            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            touch_upline(x,y);
            invalidate();
            drawLineOnLayout1(x,y);
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }
private void drawLineOnLayout1(float x,float y)
{
    drawing.mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
    drawing.mCanvas.drawLine(mX, mY, x, y, mPaint);
    drawing.mPath.reset();  
}
    public void eraseAll()
    {
        mBitmap.eraseColor(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT);
        mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
    }

    public void startErasing()
    {
        mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
    }
    public void initializePaintOnject()
    {
        mPaint.setXfermode(null);
        mPaint.setAlpha(0xFF);
    }

}
}
```

and **main.xml** is this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </LinearLayout>
     <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this.It may help you ...........

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        RelativeLayout relativeLayout= (RelativeLayout) (findViewById(R.id.mainLayout));
        relativeLayout.addView(new Drawing(this));
    }

}  

class Drawing extends View{
    private Canvas mCanvas = null;
    private Path mPath = null;
    private Paint mBitmapPaint = null;
    private Bitmap mBitmap = null;
    private Bitmap bit=null;
    private Paint mPaint = null;
    private MainActivity baseMainActivity = null;


    public interface onDrawingViewSingleTap{
        void onDrawingViewTap(float x , float y);
    }

    public Drawing(Context c) {
        super(c);
        baseMainActivity=(MainActivity) c;
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(6);//This sets the width of signature

        Display display =baseMainActivity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();

        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(display.getWidth(), display.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);// 320*480  // For setting size of screen to draw Bitmap

        mPath = new Path();
        mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
        mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
        onDraw(mCanvas);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        try{
            canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);//Color.WHITE //To change background color of Application
            if(bit!=null)
                canvas.drawBitmap(bit, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
            else
                canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);

        }catch(Exception e){}
        if(bit==null)
            canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);

        bit=null;

    }
    private float mX, mY;
    private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
        mPath.reset();
        mPath.moveTo(x, y);
        mX = x+1;
        mY = y+1;

    }

    private void touch_upline(float x,float y) {
        mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
        mCanvas.drawLine(mX, mY, x, y, mPaint);
        mPath.reset();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            touch_start(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            eraseAll();
            touch_upline(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            touch_upline(x,y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void eraseAll()
    {
        mBitmap.eraseColor(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT);
        mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
    }



}
```

and **main.xml** is this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/mainLayout" >



</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Many thanks.But it erases everything while drawing a new line. As I stated, I'll need to draw multiple lines. Also, I should be able to select a line/vertex (in selection mode) - to modify the position of whole line or a vertex.

Comment: @Prasoon Please use the code,I have posted below of this post.

Comment: The another post(code) does not erase your old line if you draw new line(I have posted here two answers,plz check another one)